# Success submit message with request parameter "name" value within a register form

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I´m using the following example for a register form in a cloud page, but I want to show the "First Name" written by the user when the success message appears. It is possible to store this value in a variable to achieve this?

```
%%[

if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then

  InsertData(
        "Registrations",
        "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
        "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
        "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
        "Email", RequestParameter("email")
       )

endif

]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      %%[ if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then ]%%
         <p>Thank you for submitting your details.</p>
      %%[ else ]%%
      <h2>Register</h2>
      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
         <label>First name</label>
         <input type="text" name="firstname">
         <label>Last name</label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname">
         <label>Company</label>
         <input type="text" name="company">
         <label>Email</label>
         <input type="text" name="email">
         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true" />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      %%[ endif ]%%
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by storing the submitted values for later use:

```
%%[

if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then

SET @firstname = RequestParameter("firstname")
SET @LastName = RequestParameter("lastname")
SET @Company = RequestParameter("company")
SET @email = RequestParameter("email")

  InsertData(
        "Registrations",
        "FirstName", @firstname,
        "LastName", @LastName,
        "Company", @Company,
        "Email", @email
       )

endif

]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      %%[ if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then ]%%
         <p>Thank you for submitting your details, %%=v(@firstname)=%%.</p>
      %%[ else ]%%
      <h2>Register</h2>
      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
         <label>First name</label>
         <input type="text" name="firstname">
         <label>Last name</label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname">
         <label>Company</label>
         <input type="text" name="company">
         <label>Email</label>
         <input type="text" name="email">
         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true" />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      %%[ endif ]%%
   </body>
</html>
```

**References:** 
 - [AMPscript Keywords - setting variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm) 
 - [V()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/v.htm)
 - [InsertData()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertdata.htm)